# How to set SSRS parameter panel on the top?

Tags: layout, reporting-services, parameters, location

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 to develop a SSRS page. When I use "Preview" mode in Visual Studio, parameters are at top of report page, just as the snapshot shows:

[image]

However, the parameter panel is moved to right hand side after I deployed reports to a sharepoint 2008 site.  How could I get Parameter Panel to the top as in preview mode?

P.S. What if I make two webparts for parameters and table separately in one dashboard, will this approach work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a report wrapper as detailed here could help.

[Report Wrapper](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoftbob/archive/2009/08/20/a-wrapper-for-running-sql-server-2008-reporting-services-reports-anonymously.aspx)

Comment: Hi @glh, thx for sharing this! have you tried out this approach before?

Comment: No I haven't but upon reading it it looked just like your issue. I hope it works.